# convert JSON file with multiple keys to one pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I try to convert this JSON file to dataframe ,I use `json_normalize("key_name")` I can convert one key to one dataframe , but I need to convert all the key to one dataframe

```js
{
    "dlg-00a7a82b": [
        {
            "utteranceID": 0,
            "source": "Hi there! How can I help?",
            "target": "Hallo! Wie kann ich helfen?"
        },
        {
            "utteranceID": 1,
            "source": "Hey, ich muss mein Auto zum Mechaniker bringen und ich würde gerne Intelligent Auto Imports besuchen.",
            "target": "Hey there, I need to take my car to mechanic and I would like to see Intelligent Auto imports."
        }
    
     ],
    "dlg-00abd8c8": [
        {
            "utteranceID": 0,
            "source": "hey there, how can i help you today?",
            "target": "Hallo, wie kann ich Ihnen heute helfen?"
        },
        {
            "utteranceID": 1,
            "source": "Hallo. Können Sie mir bei der Bestellung einer neuen Pizzeria namens Bella Luna behilflich sein?",
            "target": "Hi. Are you able to assist me by placing an order at a new pizzeria called Bella Luna?"
        },
        {
            "utteranceID": 2,
            "speaker": "agent",
            "source": "i sure can. what would u like to order from bella luna?",
            "target": "Sicher kann ich das. Was möchten Sie bei bella luna bestellen?"
        }]

}
```

like this dataframe

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA3Dy.png

Comment: Are in the dictionary many `dlg-xxxxxx` keys?

Comment: if the JSON file is read as object js the `df = pd.DataFrame(js["dlg-00a7a82b"])`

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes there is more than one key

Comment: @Nabeel See my answer.

Comment: @AndrejKesely  "data argument can't be an iterator "

Comment: @Nabeel Maybe it's version of pandas? I use `pandas==1.0.3`. I updated my answer (put `list()` around the `chain()`)

Comment: @AndrejKesely it's working thank you very much  for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for example `itertools.chain` to load the data (`json_data` is your data from the question):

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(json_data.values()))

print(df)
```

EDIT:

Try to put `list()` around the chain to put data into a list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(json_data.values())))
```

Prints:

```
   utteranceID                                             source                                             target speaker
0            0                          Hi there! How can I help?                        Hallo! Wie kann ich helfen?     NaN
1            1  Hey, ich muss mein Auto zum Mechaniker bringen...  Hey there, I need to take my car to mechanic a...     NaN
2            0               hey there, how can i help you today?            Hallo, wie kann ich Ihnen heute helfen?     NaN
3            1  Hallo. Können Sie mir bei der Bestellung einer...  Hi. Are you able to assist me by placing an or...     NaN
4            2  i sure can. what would u like to order from be...  Sicher kann ich das. Was möchten Sie bei bella...   agent
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

your json as sample_json

```
list_json = sample_json['dlg-00a7a82b']
parsed_json = json.dumps(list_json)
dict_json = json.loads(parsed_json)
df = pandas.DataFrame(dict_json, columns=dict_json[0].keys())
```

output:

```
utteranceID                                             source                                             target
0            0                          Hi there! How can I help?                        Hallo! Wie kann ich helfen?
1            1  Hey, ich muss mein Auto zum Mechaniker bringen...  Hey there, I need to take my car to mechanic a...
2            0               hey there, how can i help you today?            Hallo, wie kann ich Ihnen heute helfen?
3            1  Hallo. Können Sie mir bei der Bestellung einer...  Hi. Are you able to assist me by placing an or...
4            2  i sure can. what would u like to order from be...  Sicher kann ich das. Was möchten Sie bei bella...
```